# Java equals() and hashcode() during automatic code generation

Tags: java, sql

I am working on a project where code gets automatically generated based upon an MySQL library. It is somewhat like JPA, but not quite.

This is an example bean:

```
public class TemplateBean implements Bean {
    private Integer templateId;
    private Integer businessPartnerId;

    public TemplateBean(final Integer businessPartnerId) {
        this.businessPartnerId = businessPartnerId;
    }

    private TemplateBean(final Object nullObject, final Integer templateId, final Integer businessPartnerId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
        this.businessPartnerId = businessPartnerId;
    }

    public TemplateBean(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        this(null, rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2));
    }

    public Integer getTemplateId() {
        return templateId;
    }

    public void setTemplateId(final Integer templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }

    public Integer getBusinessPartnerId() {
        return businessPartnerId;
    }

    public void setBusinessPartnerId(final Integer businessPartnerId) {
        this.businessPartnerId = businessPartnerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Template(" + templateId + ", " + businessPartnerId + ")";
    }
}
```

Now I need it to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. I of course have access to all data that is available from SQL, so I think implementing `equals()` should be doable, but how am I going to create a good `hashCode()`?

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can let Eclipse to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` for you. Source > Generate Hashcodes and Equals then click the fields where you want to base your object's equality.

Comment: you should have a look on http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html and http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html - simply append your fields to the builders to dynamically generate `equals()` and `hashcode()`

Comment: And if you use Netbeans: ALT+INSERT > equals&hashcode.

Comment: Or in Guava, [`Objects.hashCode`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: @onepotato ,assylias Please read the question, I am talking about auto generated code, not human-typed code.

Comment: Or in plain Java 7: `Objects.hash(filed1, field2, field3)`

Comment: @JBNizet Netbeans does add prime numbers though in the generation. Maybe that's the reason why it is used above Objects.hash(Object...)?

Comment: No. The reason is probably that it exists only since Java 7. It's probably also marginally faster because it doesn't need to box primitive fields and to create an array, but it's much less readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest to use [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder;


public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String version;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, object,);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }

    or

    /*
     * equal() method with exclude fields.
     * it will neglect id and version fields.
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, object, "id", "version");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a nice option, such that I don't have to build the functions myself in my generator, and moreover I am more confident that the commons' `hashCode()` is correct.

Comment: Beware of using all fields in a bean to compute `hashCode()` and `equals()`, specially when the bean represents database data. For example, comparing primary keys is generally undesirable (because you would be checking identity, not equality). Also, you could do potentially expensive comparisons, for example two blobs. My advice is to choose the fields used to compute the `equals()` carefully, not rely on reflection.

Comment: After more thinking I realised that it does add reflection in every single call of `equals()` resp. `hashcode()`, so aren't `HashMap`s and `Set`s, etc. getting very expensive to work with then?

Comment: @skiwi You could use HashCode/EqualsBuilder without reflection and append the desired fields to the builders. just look at the documentatation and keep in mind what EmirCalabuch mentioned

Answer (score 0):

One very convenient way is to use the [@EqualsAndHashCode](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html) annotation provided by Groovy. Using this is as simple as

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TemplateBean implements Bean {
  // implementation omitted
}
```

This will generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods based on the class' properties using an algorithm similar to the one outlined in the book Effective Java.

Because the annotation is implemented via an AST transformation, it can be used in Java or Groovy classes, though you will of course need the Groovy library on your classpath to use it.